# Retriving Single column data from Parse Server and display in a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform

I am new to android and don't have that much knowledge about the database.

I created class Named "`topics`" in parse server and manually added "`topicName`" column.

Now I want to retrive this topicName value/Strings in a Listview but I'm getting an error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference

Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
public class topics_class1 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final ArrayList<String> topics1 = new ArrayList<>();
    final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView_topics_class1);
    final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, topics1);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("topics");        
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null){

                for (int i=0; i< objects.size(); i++) {
                    topics1.add(objects.get(i).getString("topicName"));
                }
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                }

            else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
 }
}
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView_topics_class1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="89dp" />
```

Comment: are u able to retrieve the data properlu

Comment: where did u call the XML file

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Just so you know, Parse Queries have the option of "selecting" what values to retrieve from the server. This is very good practice if you know you aren't going to be needing any more data from an object. I suppose if your class only has a single column it doesn't matter, but say you had more columns, you could select the keys you want to go to the client to reduce data usage, as well as not expose your entire schema to anyone sniffing it out. This combined with proper ACL / CLP usage leads to much better security, adn is easier to implement from the get go than add later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error itself explain

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

you did not `setContentView(layout)`. that's why u getting error 
try setting 
`setContentView(R.layout.layoutname);`

and get ListView accordingly

`final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_topics_class1);`

Let me know if u have any other question

Comment: Thank you. i feel stupid. Now it just displays empty page no data retrieved

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, planets);

               ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("topics");
//query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("topicName"));
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null){


           // Toast.makeText(topics_class1.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            for (int i=0; i< objects.size(); i++) {
                topics1.add(objects.get(i).getString("topicName"));
            }
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            }

        //}
        else {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

});
    }
}
```

Follow this way and implement it

XML Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 

android:layoutwidth="matchparent" 

android:layoutheight="matchparent" 

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activityverticalmargin" 

android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activityhorizontalmargin" 

android:paddingRight="@dimen/activityhorizontalmargin" 

android:paddingTop="@dimen/activityverticalmargin" 

tools:context=".MainActivity" > 

<ListView android:layoutwidth="fillparent" 

android:layoutheight="fillparent" 

android:id="@+id/listView"> 

</ListView> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do create a layout for XML